# How to detect multiple markers on Google Maps at same location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I used Google Maps in an app and it is likely that multiple markers are attached to same location where each marker represent a person. In this situation user will not know that there are other markers/persons behind this particular marker.

I looked around to handle this situation and one question on So suggests that I can display a single marker and associate all persons with that single marker.

I want to appear toast if multiple user at same location or display multiple user list.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: you can do [clustering of location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)

Answer (score 2):

The Simplest way is to use clustering. You can cluster multiple marker into one
using clusterManager
Please refer to following link for detailed explaination

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

A demo for the same is given here

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java